# Buildnumber maven plugin returns null

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

My greetings!

I have worked out really a ton of documentation, but still I get the same error :(
I use Buildnumber maven plugin to get the svn version, but it returns null all of the time.

Here is the pom:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
             <phase>validate</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>create</goal>
               </goals>
          </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
           <revisionOnScmFailure/>
           <doCheck>false</doCheck>
           <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>

...

    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
            <build.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.timestamp>
        </properties>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.*.main.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                <build-timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</build-timestamp>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also, I have a Tortoise svn configured in my path and all of the requirements are done, that are noted in the official documentation. The builds, cleans, installs are all successful, but still SVN version is NULL.

I would really appreciate your help, I've spent like several hours making this thing to work...

EDIT - my scm config stub

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://none</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://none</developerConnection>
    <url>scm:svn:https://none</url>
</scm>
```

Comment: Please use an up-to-date version of the buildnumber plugin (current version is: 1.1).

Comment: Already did. That is an old snapshot.

Comment: I have already fixed the codelines, dont pay attention to the up-comment. Still null, version 1.1

Comment: Change the entry into something usefull <revisionOnScmFailure/> like <revisionOnScmFailure>XXXX</revisionOnScmFailure> just for test purposes to see whats wrong.

Comment: Ok, I have just put some stuff in the parameters, but it didn't change anyting - it doesnt give an error! The intersting thing is that when I was digging in the source code of this plugin, I saw that if the revision is null, it should set a "0" as revision, but I receive just null. Is there something that I should configure about the SVN or my SVN provider?

Nothing happens, if I set the revision num in the revOnScmFailure.

Comment: Has this project been committed to svn yet or is it a brand new project?  I seem to remember seeing "null" for new projects I hadn't committed yet... but that was a while ago.

Comment: Nope. It is a pretty old project. Like a year ago. Please, respond to the answers, it is better to communicate over there and I would be able at least to give you an up-vote. :)

Comment: Could you post your `<scm>` configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that TortoiseSVN was not in my path. So I had to install something like SilkSVN, so I would be able to use its' libs in the system path.

Comment: I have TortoiseSVN in my Path variable of system environments. What do you mean with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I tried you configuration and I didn't find any direct problems except from a few configuration issues.

First of all the `<properties/>` section you have in the `<configuration/>` part of the `maven-jar-plugin` does not belong there. See [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables) how they should be used.

Then you should tell the fully qualified class for the `<mainClass/>` tag. The asterisk won't work.

When it comes to the `scm` part you'll have to have the `<scm/>` tags added to your `pom.xml` as well as a command line svn client.

This is the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` created when I ran `mvn install` with your config:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: maba
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_07
Main-Class: com.*.main.Main
Implementation-Build: 8
build-timestamp: 2012-10-30 09:09
Class-Path: lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar
```

As you can see I didn't get `NULL` value for the `Implementation-Build`. As stated earlier the `Main-Class: com.*.main.Main` is not going to work either.

In order to be able to help you more you will need to post some more information, like the `<scm/>` tag for example.

Comment: I know about the mainclass - I just hide the name of my company ,lol. =)